# Seeking advice on how to improve a specific question, it seems simple but has not gotten a response (after 2 days)?

Tags: discussion, editing

I would appreciate feedback on how to improve a recently asked question, [Without multi-level modeling, how to handle within-study replication in a meta-analysis, where the study is the unit of replication?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16547/without-multi-level-modeling-how-to-handle-within-study-replication-in-a-meta-an) would be appreciated.

I feel that the question itself is simple and straightforward, and for this reason am a little surprised that it has not yet been answered.

Is it clear? Does it have appropriate tags? How could I improve it?

Answer (score 5):

I do not see any particular reason why you would not get an answer to your question (which is ok, IMO), provided someone knows what it is all about (I mean, someone having experience with meta-analytical studies).

It may take some time for you to get an answer: usually few days, but we've seen accepted answers coming after 2 months or more! You have probably noticed that you got a comment, and some votes. That means that your question was read by some users on this site. Don't worry, someone will come with a good answer (not necessarily during the weekend, but who knows?)... If by the end of the next week you still haven't any response, you might try to update your question to add further information.

Comment: As I like to say, "nobody should be more committed to getting an answer to your question than you." So yes, subsequent edits to refine, explain, are always helpful. Even self-answers.